# Why dropping and creating a PK in oracle12c makes the PK disappear from `all_indexes`?

Tags: oracle, indexing, primary-key, oracle12c

I'm trying to reset a primary key "hail mary" style - drop and create.

But, afterwards, it disappears from the `all_indexes` table.

The PK appears to be there because the behavior is the correct one:

1. When trying to create it again, it says I can only create a single primary key.
2. Also, cannot insert 2 rows with same ids - unique constraint violation.

Script:

```
set echo on;
-- whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
set timing on
SET LINESIZE 2000

create table MY_TABLE (
    date_col DATE DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    hash NUMBER(19) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    value1 NUMBER(19) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    value2 NUMBER(19) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (date_col, id, hash)
);
-- Res: Table created.

CREATE INDEX MY_TABLE_I ON MY_TABLE (id, hash, date_col ASC);
-- Res: Index created.

select index_name from all_indexes where table_name = 'MY_TABLE' order by index_name;
-- Res: MY_TABLE_I, MY_TABLE_PK

ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP primary key;
-- Res: Table altered.
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (date_col, id, hash);
-- Res: Table altered.
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (date_col, id, hash);
-- Res: ORA-02260: table can have only one primary key

insert into MY_TABLE values (SYSDATE, 1, 123456, 10, 20);
-- Res: 1 row created.
insert into MY_TABLE values (SYSDATE, 1, 123456, 10, 20);
-- Res: ORA-00001: unique constraint (ALIK.MY_TABLE_PK) violated

select index_name from all_indexes where table_name = 'MY_TABLE' order by index_name;
-- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
-- Res: !!!!! Just MY_TABLE_I !!!!!
-- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

**Any idea why the PK disappears from `all_indexes` after PK recreation?**

DB version: 12.1.0.2.0

Cheers.

Comment: You wont be getting ORA-00001: unique constraint (ALIK.MY_TABLE_PK) violated since you are using sysdate which has time also and when you insert a new row it will have different timestamp. Answer to your original query is well explained by @Chris.

Comment: @mohdatif - dates are only granular to the second, it's entirely possible to run two inserts within one second and get the same value for sysdate for each

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add a primary key or unique constraint, the database checks if there's an existing index with the same leading columns. If there is, the database can use that.

The database will do this even if the index columns are in a different order to the constraint. So as `MY_TABLE_I` has the same columns as the PK, the database uses that.

If you look in `*_constraints`, you should find that the PK uses the index `MY_TABLE_I`:

```
select constraint_name, index_name
from   user_constraints
where  table_name = 'MY_TABLE' 
and    constraint_type = 'P';

CONSTRAINT_NAME    INDEX_NAME   
MY_TABLE_PK        MY_TABLE_I
```

To avoid this, use the `using index` clause to define/specify the index you want the PK to use:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE 
  ADD CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_PK 
  PRIMARY KEY (date_col, id, hash)
  USING INDEX ( 
    CREATE INDEX MY_TABLE_PK ON MY_TABLE (date_col, id, hash) 
  );
```

Comment: There's a downside for manually creating the PK index. If you'll drop the PK, the index will remain and you'll need to manually drop the index as well, like `alter table my_table drop primary key DROP INDEX`.

Comment: It's still strange that another index implicitly took over as the PK index.

Comment: If you want to be sure the database drops the index when removing the primary key add the `drop index` clause

Comment: There are pros and cons to both creating a new index vs implicitly using one. Using an existing index saves the database having to create a new one - on large tables this can take a long time. Plus it's common join/filter on all the columns of a primary key with equality conditions, so the order of columns is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, as I understand what Chris wrote, another index took over the PKs index - even though it's not in the correct order.

This means that if I query, for example, just by `date_col`, the query would be slow as it's the last param of the index that took over.

Another solution would be to first delete any index that has a set of values similar to the PK before deleting the PK.

So, in order to get to the same state, I'll need to delete the index so it won't take over. Example:

```
DROP INDEX MY_TABLE_I;
-- Res: Index dropped.

ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP primary key;
-- Res: Table altered.

ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (date_col, id, hash);
-- Res: Table altered.

CREATE INDEX MY_TABLE_I ON MY_TABLE (id, hash, date_col ASC);
-- Res: Index created.

select index_name from all_indexes where table_name = 'MY_TABLE' order by index_name;
-- Res: MY_TABLE_PK and MY_TABLE_I
```

Comment: You can also do `ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP primary key drop index` which combines the first two statements into one

Comment: Right. I wanted to get to the same state as before - auto index (not manual).